# Which approach is the most RESTful

Tags: rest, api

As a team we are preparing a REST API for handling chargers' operations.
Let's say we have a part of the code that is responsible for starting charging and for stopping charging.
We want to provide users (on mobile app) a way to start or stop the charger through our API.
Which of these is the most RESTful approach?

```
/{charger_external_id}/charging?action=[start|stop]
vs
/{charger_external_id}/start_charging
vs
/{charger_external_id}/charging/start
```

Comment: [Sharing your research helps everyone](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/why-is-research-important). Tell us what you've tried and why it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [ask]

Comment: The approach that is "most RESTful" is the one that most closely conforms to Roy Fielding's thesis.

Comment: Looking at your question, it doesn't seem to me that *any* of your URLs represent a RESTful approach.  These URLs look more like [RPC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call).  RESTful URLs would embody a resource URL and an HTTP verb, as in a PUT request to `https://example.com/someresource`.

Comment: @RobertHarvey That sounds like a class that can only ever [9 methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods). Your URLs can model all kinds of objects, but how do you model all the various actions objects can perform, such as starting/ceasing to charge?

Comment: @Alexander: In a REST-like environment, such actions are typically embodied in a POST (the "catch-all" verb), a socket, or some other communication mechanism.  Roy Fielding's thesis doesn't have much to say about such actions, though.

Comment: The best answer you can get at this moment is "read more about REST". Because REST is more than URLs like @RobertHarvey already pointed.

Comment: [This](http://www.looah.com/source/view/2284) is actually a pretty good read.

Comment: "That sounds like a class that can only ever 9 methods."   YES!  That's exactly right.  More precisely, all resources everywhere have the same 9 methods.

Comment: I'm being lose with "exactly" - it's more than 9, we're talking about resources, not classes, and about message semantics, not "methods".  But the general idea in HTTP is that all resources share the same message semantics from the transport-a-document-over-a-network domain.

Comment: "That sounds like a class that can only ever *standardized* 9 methods", which allows you to decouple your applications and use off the shelf middlewares (e.g. caches, proxies, load balancers, auth) as they understood the messaging semantic of your application. Having a small, fixed set of methods with well defined semantics is one of the main reason why REST is increasingly useful as your application scalability grows.

Answer (score 2):

> Which of these is the most RESTful approach?

Think about how you would do it on a web site.

We might, for instance, have a web page for each charger, that gives you a bunch of information about the current state of the charger.  From that page, there would be links to two forms - one to use when you want to start charging, one to use when you want to stop charging.

Clicking on one of those links would take you to the form (which might be somewhere on the charger page itself, or might be in a different document).

The form would have input controls to collect other data that might be needed for this use case, and metadata that describes to the browser how to create the request when the form is submitted.

Because changing the state of the charger is not [essentially read only](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.1), you would normally have [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) as the form method, and the data from the input controls (including any hidden controls described by the form) would be encoded into the request body.

As [Robert Bräutigam](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/418120/199871) notes, the spelling of the identifiers doesn't matter very much, because the browser just follows links and submits forms.

One case where the spelling can matter is if the browser is caching web pages - if the user changes the state of the charger, you probably (?) want to [invalidate](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-4.4) any previously cached copies of the charger web page.  That might mean that the charger web page itself is the target of the web form.

```
POST /{external-id} HTTP/2.0
Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded

action=START%20CHARGING
```

It doesn't matter at all what identifiers are used to find the forms

```
/{external_id}#start-charging
/{external_id}/start-charging#start-charging
/{external_id}/charging/start#start-charging
/start-charging/?external_id={external_id}#start-charging
/4d6b0c66-765b-477b-b7f5-65fc612869d2#start-charging
```

Those are all *fine*.  (If that doesn't seem right, then a good talk to review is Stefan Tilkov's [REST: I don't Think it Means What You Think it Does](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pspy1H6A3FM)).  The identifiers with the external-id in the URI may be easier to generalize.

If you are using representations that don't have standardized support for fragments, then you are more likely to want to have each form in a page of its own, with its own unique identifier.

---

If you wanted a more declarative style of API, it might be achieved this way: the server provides a document describing the charger in some standardized schema.  That schema includes some field that describes the state of the charger.

To change that state, the client edits its local copy of the document to change the state value, and then sends these edits to the server.  That would normally be a PUT request (if you send the clients entire copy) or a PATCH request (if you send only the diffs between the two copies).

The expectation here is that the server could compare the two documents, see what has changed, and make the appropriate change locally.

Note that, once again, the spelling of the identifiers don't matter at all; because the PUT and the PATCH would normally use the same URI as the GET request that fetched the original document.

Answer (score 2):

> Which of these is the most RESTful approach?

None of them.

REST is REpresentational State Transfer.

Lets break down what that means. You have resources in your application, a resource can be anything (a user, an address, an inventory item etc)

You represented this resource in some format (content type or media type). It could be a PNG image, it could be a geo-coordinate, it could be a particular JSON format describing this resource

Both the client and the server have enough knowledge about the resource and the representation to be able to change the state of the resource. This could be editing an imagine, it could be changing the values in the JSON file, it could be creating a new Word document etc

REST protocols, such as HTTP, provide the mechanisms to transfer these representations between the client and the server

Take a trivial example. You have a resource of an Apple. It is represented as an PNG image. The client gets the current representation of the resource from the server (via GET url), the client then edits the image and sends the new state of the resource back to the server (PUT url), and the server decides to accept this new state.

Notice in this example the client is not telling the server to how to change the state of the resource. It is not issuing commands to the client to edit the image (draw line, change color, flip image etc). The client does all the work, and then just says to the server "here I'm finished, this is the new state"

Why work that way as opposed to something like Remote Procedure Call where the client would be issuing commands such as "draw this line, now set this color, ok now flip the image"

Well it decouples the the client from the server. The client can do what ever it likes to the image so long as it is following the agreed standards negotiated between the client and server. HTTP doesn't have to care about any of that. Which is why HTTP can be used for a PNG image, a Word document, or some vendor specific Content Type you decided just for your API.

So back to your question. You have a resource, the charger. It can be in two states, charging or not charging.

Define a representation format (content type) for that so that both the client and the server know how to handle that format. It will be super simple, the charger can only be in two valid states. Publish this some where that anyone implementing a client will know the valid format of the charger resource (I'm not sure if your API is just for internal developers or if it is public.)

You can give it a name so that the client and server can communicate around this content type (eg `application/vnd.mycompany.myapp.charger+json;`)

Now the client requests the resource

```
GET /{charger_external_id}
```

and will get back the resource in a format that tells the client what state this charger is in. For example

*Request*

```
GET /{charger_external_id}
Accept: application/vnd.mycompany.myapp.charger+json;
```

*Response*

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd.mycompany.myapp.charger+json;

{
   status: 'charging'
}
```

the client can now change the state of this resource by constructing a new representation of the resource and doing a PUT request to the server

*Request*

```
PUT /{charger_external_id}
Content-Type: application/vnd.mycompany.myapp.charger+json;

{
    status: 'not charging'
}
```

Response

```
200 OK
```

The server can validated this is in fact a valid state for the resource to be in, check the client is authorized to put the resource into that state and if the server is happy to accept this state change can return a 200 OK letting the client know it has accepted this new state.

The server can now carry out any side-effects of this state change such as physically stopping something from charging.

This is REST.

Notice there is now nothing about 'starting' or 'stopping' charging in your URL. Because why would there be, your URL identifies a resource, it doesn't represent actions.

This decouples your client and server. All they both need to know is the content type you are using. Nothing needs to exist in the URL, you don't need to communicate what actions you can or cannot send to the server. The only thing you have to worry about is valid state transitions

Comment: This is an OK answer I guess for your constructed example. If the representation is more than just the one state, you will not get around having forms. Even in this example, I would prefer some indication of what the client's options are. Remember, the client is supposed to *choose* a server-provided action to proceed to a next state. Defining it in the media-type is sort-of ok, but a slight cop-out in my opinion.

Comment: The client isn't choosing a server provided action. The client is choosing a valid state for the resource to be in. What actions the server has to perform to get its representation of that resource into that state is none of the clients concern. What are or are not valid states for the resource should be already define in the content type and both the client and server know this before they start.This is no different to how a web browser understands the HTML 5 spec long before it actually downloads or edits a HTML page.

Answer (score -1):

REST is based on Hypertext. URIs don't matter.

Knowing nothing else about your exact use-case, I would model that thusly:

- **GET /**: The "homepage". Returns a list of chargers, maybe their state too, depending on what the use-case is (i.e. what the client needs) This list contains **links** to the following URIs.
- **GET /chargerid**: The individual charger. Has 1 **form** in it that starts or stops the charger, depending on which makes sense. The form submits (POSTS) to:
- **POST /chargerid/stop** or **POST /chargerid/start**: Which does the action.

Note, what matters is the "flow" and the hypertext (i.e. links and forms) with which it is realized. The URIs don't matter *at all*. All clients start at **/** and "discover" the API. All resources should have their own media-type, or one media-type which defines all "sub-types" for all these resources.

Note 2, virtually nobody does this (I mean hypertext), but this is what REST really looks like.

HTH.

Comment: "virtually nobody does this" -- yup.